# Angularjs get external page data from parameters

Tags: angularjs

I am beginning to use Angularjs.  I have this working properly.

There is a dynamically created sidebar listing all the styles.
There is a dynamically created navbar for sizes associated with that style.

When clicked style is "selected" properly.
When clicked size is "selected" properly.

I want these two selections to be parameters in a url that I GET and display within a specific DIV.  So the url would look like ...http://xxxddd.com/inventory/{{style}}/{{size}}

I have absolutely no idea where to go from here.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("alt", []); 


    app.controller('StyleController', function(){
this.style = '';

this.selectStyle = function(newValue){
  this.style = newValue;
};

this.isSelected = function(styleName){
  return this.style === styleName;
 };
});

app.controller('SizeController', function(){
this.size = '';

this.selectSize = function(newValue){
  this.size = newValue;
};

this.isSelected = function(sizeName){
  return this.size === sizeName;
};
});

</script>
```

I am very new at angular.  I hope someone can help me.  This is the main hangup with my project right now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a service that utilizes AngularJS' [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) library to make a GET request. Look at the documentation and see how to pass parameters (style/size).

You will then want to use AngularJS' [Dependency Injection (DI)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to inject your service into your controller and call its method which has the `$http` call.

Comment: I have always cut and paste and worked through code until it is functional.  This is way complicated to me... I think I probably need to back up a bit and try and figure it out.  I have done similar things with javascript... on click change div value... return html in this div... etc.  Angularjs seems better. Thank you for your help.  I will try.

Comment: When first starting out with AngularJS, you'll find it helpful to research and conceptualize how AngularJS functions from a high-level (as a framework) before diving into coding. If you have past experience with vanilla JavaScript or jQuery, I would highly suggest reading articles that differentiate how JavaScript/jQuery and AngularJS are used.